# How to serialize immutable struct

Tags: serialization, struct, .net-core, json.net, immutability

I am trying to serialize an immutable struct using `JSon.NET`and i do not how to do it .The result of the serialization is an empty json `{}`.I would prefer to use `JsonNET` and not something heavy like the `BinaryFormatter`.

**Struct**

```
[Serializable]
    public struct Settings : IEquatable<Settings> {

        private readonly (
            TimeSpan from,
            TimeSpan until,
            TimeSpan repeatInterval,
            TimeSpan popupInterval,
            string notes
        ) _value;

        [JsonIgnore]
        public TimeSpan From => _value.from;
        [JsonIgnore]
        public TimeSpan Until => _value.until;
        [JsonIgnore]
        public TimeSpan Repeat => _value.repeatInterval;
        [JsonIgnore]
        public TimeSpan PopUpInterval => _value.popupInterval;
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Notes => _value.notes;



        public Settings(
            TimeSpan from,
            TimeSpan until,
            TimeSpan repeatInterval,
            TimeSpan popUpInterval,
            string notes
        ) => _value = (
            from,
            until,
            repeatInterval,
            popUpInterval,
            notes
        );

        public bool Equals(Settings other) => _value == other._value;
        public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is Settings other && this.Equals(other);
        public override int GetHashCode() => _value.GetHashCode();
        public override string ToString() => _value.ToString();



        public static bool operator ==(Settings a, Settings b) => a.Equals(b);
        public static bool operator !=(Settings a, Settings b) => !(a == b);
    }
```

**Program**

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
            Settings settings = new Settings(new TimeSpan(0),
                new TimeSpan(0,1,1),
                new TimeSpan(1,2,3),
                new TimeSpan(2,4,3),
                "adisor");
            var obj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settings);
            var newone = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(obj);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For serialization the `JsonIgnore` attribute need to be removed from target properties. For deserialization, constructor which will be used during deserialization need to be marked with `JsonConstruct` attribute. Optionally serialization names (properties) need to be reconciled with deserialization names (here constructor parameters) via `JsonProperty` attributes.

```
    public TimeSpan From => _value.from;

    public TimeSpan Until => _value.until;

    public TimeSpan Repeat => _value.repeatInterval;

    public TimeSpan PopUpInterval => _value.popupInterval;

    public string Notes => _value.notes;

    [JsonConstructor] //choose a constructor for deserialization
    public Settings(
        TimeSpan from,
        TimeSpan until,
        [JsonProperty("Repeat")]TimeSpan repeatInterval, //same name used for serialization
        TimeSpan popUpInterval,
        string notes
    ) => _value = (
        from,
        until,
        repeatInterval,
        popUpInterval,
        notes
    );
```